# VBA automation error in Driver.start "Edge" Runtime error 80131700 automation error

Tags: excel, selenium-webdriver, selenium-edgedriver

I working on excel VBA selenium edge ..with selenium 2.0.9.0... the code runs fine on my PC but it gives error on the PC where it will run actually ..

I have this code which gives me runtime error 80131700 automation error ..

Dim driver as new selenium.EdgeDriver

Driver.start "Edge"  <<<< this is where I get error ..
AS i researched .. it was bout selenium or edge drivers ...
i have tried different drivers along with the on as per edge version. system is windows 64 bit

I tried with firewall off also .. but same error .. I have tried giving the path to start method ... but .. no use ..

Please guide ...

Dim driver as new selenium.EdgeDriver

Driver.start "Edge"  <<<< this is where I get error ..

I have tried
driver.start "Edge", "C;\users\path\to\edgedrivers.exe"
but no use ..
when I manually run it form the selenium folder the edge drivers run successfully but when I run VBA code in excel .. it gives error
I tried different versions of the edge drivers .. and reinstalled selenium basic 2.0.9.0
please guide ..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.